# Java Android AlertDialogs Show on infowindow OnClick for google maps v2

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

i would like to ask a question with regards to AlertDialogs which i would like to use in GoogleMaps V2. I read about the custom InfoWindow documentation from the android developers and noticed that they advised not to put any interaction widgets (Buttons, Textbox etc etc) onto an OnClick function. Now, i would like to know if i could use a default alert dialog and put it into an OnClick function for the custom InfoWindow. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work fine. The reason why you should not (and cannot, really) put interactive elements in an `InfoWindow` is because the `InfoWinow` is statically rendered when shown, making any interactive elements you place in it effectively useless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for replying so late =D I also just found out about this not too long ago after reading the developer's documentation for android so thanks for your help =D